# extract email from column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, trim

Trying to extract the email from a column in an excel sheet using the following formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$A1&" "," ",REPT(" ",40)),
 FIND(REPT("@",COLUMNS($A1:A1)),SUBSTITUTE
 (SUBSTITUTE(" "&$A1&" "," ",REPT(" ",40)),"@",REPT("@",COLUMNS($A1:A1)),COLUMNS($A1:A1)))-40,80))
```

The formula works for the most part, however some of the records still include other text.

For example, one of the records looks like this:

```
**TEST** John Beasley,jbeasley@usa.com,7575551212
```

After using the above formula, I get the following results:

```
Beasley,jbeasley@usa.com,7575551212
```

Here's another example:

```
USA-USA/J Beasley/jbeasley@usa.com/757-555-1212
```

Results after using formula:

```
Beasley/jbeasley@usa.com/757-555-1212
```

Here is an example of when the formula works (before):

```
**US AMA TES DATA** John Beasley, jbeasley@usa.com
```

Which yields the following results:

```
jbeasley@usa.com
```

So the formula works, but it also does not work.

How can I write the formula so that it extracts everything except the actual email address?

Comment: If you have access to `LAMBDA()` functionality, you could have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363987/9758194) where you'll find a generic 'split' function that does the trick along with the xpath expression provided by Scott. If you don't know the specific delimiters, just cram all characters in that you can see that devide substrings.

Answer (score 1):

If one has it, use FILTERXML:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",","),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'@')]")
```

FILTERXML was introduced in Excel 2013 and only on PC not Mac.

[image]

If does not have FILTERXML then we can use:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",","),",",REPT(" ",999)),FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",","),",",REPT(" ",999)))-500,999))
```

[image]

Comment: Testing........

Comment: No luck... I get the same exact data and text.

Comment: @JohnBeasley then there is something different in your data that is not in what you posted.  As you can see both formula that I posted are tested and return the correct value.

Comment: @JohnBeasley, My guess is that the `,` is not a true `,` but some other character that looks like a `,`

Comment: The text can be random.  I tried to provide a couple of examples, but there are quite a few.  The second function you provided works a little better, but it excludes others.  Seems like I may have to run a couple of functions in order to get it to work.

Comment: You will need to get them to a common divider.  You will need to account for each that can happen.  If you do not tell Excel what the divider is, it cannot interpolate.

Comment: I recommend you create a user function with VBA, and then use it as a formula. Please take a look at this link https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1272-excel-extract-email-address.html

Comment: Do you think if I brought this into an Access database, I could write a query that would extract the email? (unfortunately, Access is the only DB I am allowed to use).